# EL wire + inverter questions

Tags: voltage, ac, el-wire

I have a question on connecting 3V EL wires to a 12V unit inverter. I know that is not okay to do so in a DC circuit, but I don't know if it is okay to connect them in an AC circuit.

Here is the link to the 12V unit inverter:
[https://www.amazon.com/uxcell-Black-Cable-Driver-Inverter/dp/B00E0IVS0Y/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_product_top?ie=UTF8](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00E0IVS0Y)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Data and facts will improve the chances to get help.

Answer (score 1):

The 3V will apply only to the inverter input. The "wires" themselves are "probably"  similar whether the inverter is 3V battery input or 12V automotive input.

Typical EL wire voltage/frequency (and thus inverter output) is 60-120V RMS at 0.4 to 2kHz.

Answer (score 0):

The image in the link reads DC12V so you should only supply the inverter with 12V DC. EL wire requirements vary. Your question is a little difficult to parse, but in my experience EL wires need a relatively high AC voltage (~100v) at a high frequency (~60-2Khz) in order to operate. You should check the specs on the wire if you want to use something other than the suggested inverter.